# How to simply use a module for different classes together?like (String, Array, Hash)

Tags: ruby

I wrote code for an Enumerables module:

```
module Enumerables
  def palindrome?
    if self.is_a?(Hash)
      return false
    else
      self.join('').gsub(/\W/,"").downcase == self.join('').gsub(/\W/,"").downcase.reverse
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is, I have to write these:

```
class Array
  include Enumerables
end

class Hash
  include Enumerables
end
```

to make the code run successfully.

Is there an easy way to make the "palindrome?" method run with different instance types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`ObjectSpace.each_object` iterator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) with a filter to find classes that include Enumerable and extend them dynamically:

```ruby
# XXX: this iterator yields *every* object in the interpreter!
ObjectSpace.each_object do |obj|
  if obj.is_a?(Class) && (obj < Enumerable)
    obj.module_eval { include Enumerables }
  end
end

[1,2,1].palindrome? # => true
{}.palindrome? # => false
```

Now the trick is to write something that works for all enumerable types in a meaningful way!  Note also that this sort of metaprogramming is fun for kicks but has serious implications if you plan to use it for anything other than "toy" programs.

Comment: You can just modify Enumerable (see my answer). I think it is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @mechanicalfish: yes, if OP's intent were to extend only "Enumerable" instances then modifying the Enumerable module would be cleaner; however, I suspect he is also interested in extending arbitrary types  (String).

Answer (score 3):

The module is not `Enumerables` but `Enumerable` so if you have

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    ...
  end
end
```

it will work without includes.

If you want to add this method to all objects see texasbruce's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open any class below Object level and add this method there. Then it will be accessible to almost all built-in types and all user defined types.

You can put it in `Object`, `Kernel`(it is a module), `BasicObject`.

For example,

```
class Object
  def foo
    puts "hello"
  end
end
[].foo
```